# Why is not saving the changes in the variable?

Tags: c++, oop

I'm kind of noobie when it comes to OOP, so I'm probably making a mistake, but I can't find it, here's the part of the code that fails:

The util file is just a file with the error messages

In main.cc:

```
int main(){

 Ship imperialDestroyer(IMPERIAL);
 Ship rebelShip(REBEL);

 cout<<imperialDestroyer<<endl; //this just print the ship, you can ignore it
 cout<<rebelShip<<endl;

 imperialDestroyer.improveFighter(); //this is what fails

 cout<<imperialDestroyer<<endl;
}
```

In Ship.cc:

```
bool Ship::improveFighter(){

int num, cantidad, cost;
char option, respuesta;
bool improved = false;

cout << "Select fighter number: ";
cin >> num;
num = num-1;

if(num > this->fleet.getNumFighters() || num < 0)
  Util::error(WRONG_NUMBER);

else{
  cout << "What to improve (v/a/s)?";
  cin>>option;

if(option!='v' && option!='a' && option!='s')
  Util::error(UNKNOWN_OPTION);

else{
  cout << "Amount: ";
  cin >> cantidad;

  if(option == 'v')
cost = 2 * cantidad;

  else if(option == 'a')
cost = 3 * cantidad;

  else if(option == 's')
cost = (cantidad + 1) / 2;

  if(this->fleet.getCredits() < cost)
Util::error(NO_FUNDS);

  else{
cout << "That will cost you "<< cost <<" credits. Confirm? (y/n)";
cin >> respuesta;

if(respuesta == 'y'){
  this->fleet.improveFighter(num, option, cantidad, cost);
  improved = true;
}

  }
 }
}

return improved;
}
```

In Fleet.cc:

```
void Fleet::improveFighter(int nf, char feature, int amount, int cost){

  if(feature == 'v'){
    getFighter(nf).increaseVelocity(amount);
  }

  else if(feature == 'a'){
    getFighter(nf).increaseAttack(amount); 
  }

  else if(feature == 's'){
    getFighter(nf).increaseShield(amount);   
  }
}
```

}

In Fighter.cc:

```
Fighter Fleet::getFighter(int n) const{

  return fighters[n];
}

void Fleet::improveFighter(int nf, char feature, int amount, int cost){

  if(feature == 'v'){
    getFighter(nf).increaseVelocity(amount);
  }

  else if(feature == 'a'){
    getFighter(nf).increaseAttack(amount); 
  }

  else if(feature == 's'){
    getFighter(nf).increaseShield(amount);   
  }
}
```

For some reason when I try to improve some feature, it won't get saved.

Comment: Could you fix your indentation, please? And present your [MCVE].

Comment: `cout<<imperialDestroyer<<endl;` - Is this even compiling? If yes, show relevant code.

Comment: @Ajay: Why should it not? And how is it relevant to the question?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, because `Ship` is a class, not basic data-type. Does it define overload for `cout<<` to work?!

Comment: @Ajay: Obviously yes? And that has nothing to do with what is being asked.

Answer (score 1):

```
Fighter Fleet::getFighter(int n) const
{
  return fighters[n];
}
```

This returns a *copy* of the `Fighter` at position `n`. Modifying a copy won't affect the original.

You could return a `Fighter&` (i.e. a *reference*), but since your function is `const`, that won't work. You're going to have to decide what you want this function to *be*.

Comment: Ok, I shouldn't have used the getFighter module, thanks for the tip of "Modifying a copy won't affect the original" that helped me realized I had to use the vector fighters, is was quite simple, but I couldn't see it.